# "Value can not be null" on singleton instantiation

Tags: vb.net, exception, singleton

I have a singleton class that I am attempting to instantiate and it is giving the exception "Value cannot be null"

Im declaring a reference in my main form like:

```
Dim devices As DeviceUnderTestBindingList
```

Then instantiating in my form.load:

```
devices = DeviceUnderTestBindingList.GetInstance
```

The DeviceunderTestBindingList class is as follows:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class DeviceUnderTestBindingList
    ' DeviceUnderTest is one of my other regular classes...
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of DeviceUnderTest)

    Private Shared SingleInstance As DeviceUnderTestBindingList
    Private Shared InstanceLock As Object
    Private Shared ListLock As Object

    Private Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property GetInstance As DeviceUnderTestBindingList
        Get
            ' Ensures only one instance of this list is created.
            If SingleInstance Is Nothing Then
                SyncLock (InstanceLock)
                    If SingleInstance Is Nothing Then
                        SingleInstance = New DeviceUnderTestBindingList
                    End If
                End SyncLock
            End If
            Return SingleInstance
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

I've used the same pattern before with no problems, now all of a sudden its causing an exception, but why?

Please note: This is a VB.NET Q! I have read a lot of the C# Q's that deal with similar problems but did not understand them enough.

Comment: Which line gets the error?  Is it a run-time exception or a compile-time error?

Comment: As I mentioned, it's when I try to instantiate it, i.e., at the line `devices = DeviceUnderTestBindingList.GetInstance`, and occurs when I run the program (though is in the form.load event so is only caught if I put a Try...catch around that line)

Comment: Can you please include the stack track for the exception in your question?  I suspect it will be helpful in solving the problem.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, I dont actually know where to find the stack trace, but I think I've narrowed it down to the `SyncLock(InstanceLock)` line. If I get rid of them and the extra check for nothing then it works...

Comment: I suspected that might be the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot `SyncLock` on a null variable.  You can only `SyncLock` on a valid instance of an object.  You need to change this line:

```
Private Shared InstanceLock As Object
```

To this:

```
Private Shared InstanceLock As New Object()
```

Comment: Brilliant! Such a small thing to cause frustration!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that this issue caused me to go back and look at singleton patterns and I finally understoodhow to use the Lazy(T) pattern, though Im still not sure how thread-safe it is. here is the VB code:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Private Shared SingleInstance As Lazy(Of MyClass) = New Lazy(Of MyClass)(Function() New MyClass())

    Private sub New ()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property GetInstance
        Get
            Return SingleInstance.value
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

then declare and instantiate as in my OP.
(This only works for .NET 4 and up though)